# Image size optimization for less data usage

Tags: ios, database, image, backend

I'm working on a Instagram-like app on iOS, and I'm wondering on how to optimize the file size of each picture so the users will use as least data as possible when fetching all those pictures from my backend. It seems like it will drain data if you download the file just as it is since high resolution pictures are around 1.5MB each. Is there a way to shrink the size of the picture while maintaining the quality of the picture as much as possible?

Answer (score 3):

you can compress the image by saving it into json binary data.
OR simply core binary data.
OR elegantly Swift Realm - Core binary data.

Comment: you can also resample with core data like so:

Comment: let image = CIImage(contentsOfURL: self.URL)

let filter = CIFilter(name: "CILanczosScaleTransform")!
filter.setValue(image, forKey: "inputImage")
filter.setValue(0.5, forKey: "inputScale")
filter.setValue(1.0, forKey: "inputAspectRatio")
let outputImage = filter.valueForKey("outputImage") as! CIImage

let context = CIContext(options: [kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer: false])
let scaledImage = UIImage(CGImage: self.context.createCGImage(outputImage, fromRect: outputImage.extent()))

Comment: this post describes more about image resizing topic
http://nshipster.com/image-resizing/

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to customise image by you own! because there are lots of libraries already available for doing that.

Which are more effective and powerful.

like,

AFNetworking Api

Its is wonderful it could not only compressed images as per UIImageView current available size according to device resolution but also give you image cache flexibility.

[Here is the link of Pod File and github](https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjo26mUn5XQAhWJXBoKHY7ODdgQFggYMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FAFNetworking%2FAFNetworking&usg=AFQjCNE6c3SnPVzdrmQ1-UQ5mEf8Kl9JXg&sig2=vPwqL9MGfLV5jWzbquXXDg&bvm=bv.137904068,d.d2s)

Just try It you will love it

Comment: @More You can use cocoapod application to install it

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely check on it!

Comment: No problem you can check and if you have any question do not hesitate to ask again i will tell u further

Answer (score 0):

You can compress a UIImage by converting it into `NSData`

```
UIImage *rainyImage =[UImage imageNamed:@"rainy.jpg"];
NSData *imgData= UIImageJPEGRepresentation(rainyImage,0.1 /*compressionQuality*/); // Second parameter of this function is the compression Quality
```

Now use this `NSData` object to save or convert it into `UIImage`
To convert it again into UIImage

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.

> Image compression will loose in the image quality.